# Android phone not even charging on a Mac Mini (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, usb, mac-mini, charging, android

I'm new to OSX, so I'm probably doing something which is obviously wrong.

I have a Samsung Note and USB cable which when plugged into my Linux laptop work without any issues.

I have a late-2012 Mac Mini running Yosemite.

When I plug the phone into the Mac Mini's USB ports it does not even start charging.  I have tried three different USB ports, including ports I know are working (as I swapped the keyboard and mouse plugs).

What do I need to do for my Mac Mini to at least charge my Android Phone?

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted?  If the answer is obvious, please enlighten me.

Comment: Have you tried the phone on another computer?

Comment: @IronCraftMan Yes, I have tried it on my Linux laptop and on my Linux workstation, where it works fine. The fact that it doesn't even charge on the Mac Mini really surprised me.

Answer (score 1):

I have **zero** experience with Android, that said it may be that a driver or such (sync software for Mac?) might be needed for the Mac to 'recognize' the phone

Comment: Yes, I installed Google's Android software for OSX.  My query was that the phone didn't even charge when plugged in to the Mac Mini.  I had reasoned that I could not expect anything else to work until the phone would at least show that it was charging.

Comment: Yah sorry, you might want to head on over to http://android.stackexchange.com/ and see if they have any suggestions as most of us here have Macs and iPhones

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to buy a Cubot X15 Android phone to replace the 3+ year old Samsung Note.  It worked with the Mac Mini immediately.